# PHP login form doesnt work, doenst reload

Tags: php, html

I hope you guys can help me. I've got a php file name login.php, in this page there is a form for submitting a name and a password, and then there is checklogin.php that connects to the bd and check if the user exists.

The problem is that when I put the info about user and then submit nothing happens. It stays on the same page (login.php).

Here is the code in login.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />

</head>

  <style type="text/css">
    #Button1
    {
        width: 120px;
    }
    #Button2
    {
        width: 120px;
    }
</style>


<body onload="display_ct(),display_ct2();">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header">
<div id="Div1">
<div class="row dropdown-container fixed">
<div class="col-220">
<a id="logo" title="Back Home" href="index.htm">
<img width="220" alt="logo" src="Images/logo.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>
<div class="col-701 last">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p class="get-in-touch">
<img width="14" height="10" alt="" src="Images/flagpt.jpg"/>
<strong>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function display_c() {
              var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
              mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
          }

          function display_ct() {
              var strcount
              var x = new Date()
              var horas = x.getHours();
              var min = x.getMinutes();
              var sec = x.getSeconds();
              if (horas < 10) {
                  horas = "0" + horas;
              }
              if (min < 10) {
                  min = "0" + min;
              }
              if (sec < 10) {
                  sec = "0" + sec;
              }

              document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = horas + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " ";
              tt = display_c();
          }

      </script> <span id='ct' ></span>
</strong>
<img width="14" height="10" alt="" src="Images/flagiraque.jpg"/>
<strong>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display_c2() {
    var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
    mytime2 = setTimeout('display_ct2()', refresh)
}

function display_ct2() {
    var strcount
    var x = new Date()
    var horas1 = x.getHours() + 2;
    var min1 = x.getMinutes();
    var sec1 = x.getSeconds();

    if (horas1 < 10) {
        horas1 = "0" + horas1;
    }
    if (horas1 > 24) {
        horas1 = "0" + (horas1 - 24);
    }

    if (min1 < 10) {
        min1 = "0" + min1;
    }
    if (sec1 < 10) {
        sec1 = "0" + sec1;
    }
    document.getElementById('ct2').innerHTML = horas1 + ":" + min1 + ":" + sec1 + " ";
    tt1 = display_c2();
}

      </script> <span id='ct2' ></span>
</strong>
</p>
<p class="text-right">غرفة التجارة و الصناعة البرتغالية العراقية</p>
<p class="text-right1">Câmara do Comércio e Indústria Portugal-Iraque</p>
<p class="text-right">ژووری بازرگانی عیراق پۆرتگال</p>
</div>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="index.htm"><center>Inicio <br />  بداية  </center> </a></li>

<li onmouseover=""><center><a href="about2.htm">About Us</a></center>  <center>  حول الغرفة </center>    
    <ul class="nav first"> 
        <li><a href="MsgPresidente.htm"><center>Palavra do Presidente</center>  <center>  كلمة الرئيس  </center></a> </li>
        <li><a href="DirectionBoard.htm"><center> Direcção</center>  <center> كلمة الرئيس  </center></a> </li>
        <li><a href="ConsultiveBoard.htm"><center>Conselho Superior</center>  <center>المجلس الاستشاري </center></a></li>
        <li><a href="GeneralAssembly.htm"><center>Assembleia Geral</center>  <center>الجمعية العامة</center></a></li>
        <li><a href="FinancialCouncil.htm"><center>Conselho Fiscal</center>  <center>الهيئة المالية </center></a></li>

        <li><a href="FoundingMembers.htm"><center>Membros Fundadores</center>  <center> العضاء المؤسسين </center></a></li>   
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="Links.htm"><center>Links</center>  <center>  روابط</center></a></li>
<li><a href="Protocolos.htm"><center>Protocolos</center>  <center>  مذكرات تفاهم  </center> </a></li>
<li onmouseover=""><center><a href="news2.htm">Noticias/Fotos/Videos</a></center>  <center> اخبار و صور  </center>    
    <ul class="nav first"> 
        <li><a href="news2.htm"><center>Noticias</center>  <center> اخبار   </center> </a></li>
        <li><a href="photo1.htm"><center>Fotos</center>  <center> صور   </center></a> </li> 
        <li><a href="videos.htm"><center>Videos</center>  <center>  افلام </center></a> </li>   
    </ul>
</li>    
<li onmouseover=""><center><a href="associados2.htm">Associados</a></center>  <center> اعضاء  </center>    
    <ul class="nav first"> 
        <li><a href="HowToJoin.htm"><center>Como entrar</center>  <center>كيفية الاشتراك </center></a> </li>
        <li><a href="ListOfMembers.htm"><center>Lista de Membros</center>  <center>  قائمة الاعضاء </center></a> </li>  
    </ul>
</li>    
<li><a href="Contacts.htm"><center>Contactos</center>  <center>اتصل بنا  </center></a>     </li> 
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div class="hr">

</div> 
<div class="row fixed">
<div class="col-220">
<ul id="news-box">
<p></p>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-460 ">
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<div class="row fixed">
<div class="col-220">
    <p >

        <img width="130" height="70"   alt="emb" src="Images/smartcom.jpg"/><br>
<strong>
&copy; 2012

<a href="http://www.smartcom.pt">Smartcom,
        <br/></a>Intelligent Communications&nbsp;


</strong>
</p>
<p >
All rights reserved.
<br/>

</p>
</div>
<div class="col-460 ">

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>  
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Checklogin.php:

```
<?php
//ob_start();
//session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="ccili_userccili"; // Mysql username
$password="lKUJZhn[{w#e"; // Mysql password
$db_name="ccili_BD"; // Database name
$tbl_name="User"; // Table name


// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);


//$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE LOGINNAME='$myusername' and LOGINPASS='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE LOGINNAME='$myusername' and LOGINPASS='$mypassword'");

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.htm"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");

header("Location: login_sucess.php");
//header("Location: http://ccili.org/login_sucess.php");
die();
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
}
//ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: There is no code... Not even in the source of the question.

Comment: You paste the code in and add four spaces before every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested form tags and that doesn't quite work. The form is submitting to the first tag that has no action attribute.

Here is some more insight on the nesting issue: [Can you nest html forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)

Comment: simplify it down to what you need. one form should handle one action. What is the other form for exactly?

Comment: thank you so much databyss, the first form does nothing, the first time a i made the site it was on asp.net, and then a copied the html from there to php...

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me guess the problem - Add the action and type attribute to the form